# Finding matches in Excel files, adding to a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a business requirement where I have to read excel files and match each cell with a given keyword list and find the matches and write it into a dataframe.

I have written the code, but when the excel size is increasing (7 MB - 5 sheets, 30k * 9), the code is taking unusually long time (40 minutes), and I know that it should since I have so many for loops, but is there anyway to optimize it?

I have tried many different ways to optimize the same, but nothing worked out well.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import datetime
import numpy as np

raw_details_list = []
# there are around 10 keys and 600 values
keyword_dic = {"it spend": ['IT OpEx', 'OpEx'], "Infra": ["Dell", "Oracle"]}

def pattern(keys):
    return re.compile('|'.join([r'(?<!\w)%s(?!\w)' % re.escape(keys)]), flags=re.I)

# this is reading each cell of the excel and doing a match whether with the keyword_dic
def sheet_handler(path, page_count, row):
    try:
        global keyword_dic
        if isinstance(row, str):
            for category, keywords in keyword_dic.items():
                for keys in keywords:
                    r = pattern(keys)
                    words = r.findall(row)
                    # storing the matches in a list of dictionary
                    for i in words:
                        temp_dic = {"File Path": path, "Total Number of Page(s)/Slide(s)": page_count, "Keyword": keys,
                                    "IT Category":category}
                        raw_details_list.append(temp_dic)
    except Exception as e:
        pass

# reading the excel - all sheets and creating a dataframe
def xlsx_handler(path):
    # reading the excel file
    sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=None, header=None)
    sheet_count = len(sheets_dict)
    for name, sheet in sheets_dict.items():
        # removing float type columns
        sheet = sheet.loc[:, sheet.dtypes != np.float64]
        # reading each row, we have keep track of each cell's row and column details
        for index, row in sheet.iterrows():
            for i in range(len(row)):
                try:
                    # if the content is float, we can skip it
                    float(row[i])
                except Exception as e:
                    sheet_handler(path, sheet_count, row[i])


print(datetime.datetime.now())
xlsx_handler(r"D:\Backend Python\test\test.xlsx")
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_details_list)
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Sample data:

```
1   Oracle  ERP would be good   United states
2   Dell    Laptops UK
3   Vaio    Off-limit   India
4   Oracle 1.2  E-series    Chine
```

The output for this should somewhat look like this:

```
File Path   Pages   Keyword IT Category
D://Data    1   Oracle  Infra
D://Data    1   Oracle  Infra
D://Data    1   Dell    Infra
```

Comment: first off I think you should ditch for loops - Pandas vectorized methods could significantly help. It would also be helpful if u shared a sample of ur data (not pics, or links) with the keyword list u r trying to filter for. and include ur expected output. but really, ditch the for loops

Comment: Have uploaded sample input and expected output. I have already shared some sample keywords.

Comment: https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6 -- great read.  I should do more of this. I agree that this more of a "code review"

Comment: Sankar, now that this has been migrated, do add more explanation as to what your code *does*. See [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2438) for what makes a good Code Review question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.

The problem was I was creating the pattern `r = pattern(keys)` for each keyword (remind you i had 600 keywords) for each cell of the excel which was completely unnecessary.

So if i had a `10(rows) * 10 (columns) excel file`, the same `600` pattern was getting created `600 * 10 * 10 times`.

So I created one dictionary of patterns just once and used the same `10 * 10` times.

```
for cat,key in keyword_dic.items():
    temp = [pattern(keyword) for keyword in key]
    list_of_patterns[cat] = temp
```

Thanks everyone, for taking the time to go through the post!